# How should I test a public method call to another protected method?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I have a class:

```
class a
{
    public function b()
    {
        $arg1 = $this->service1->getArg1();
        $arg2 = $this->service2->getArg2();
        $result = $this->d($arg1, $arg2);
        if ($result) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function c()
    {
        $arg1 = $this->service3->getArg1();
        $arg2 = $this->service4->getArg2();
        $result = $this->d($arg1, $arg2);
        if ($result) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    
    protected function d($arg1, $arg2)
    {
        if ($arg1 == $arg2) {
            // do something
            // call service 5, service 6
            return $result;
        }
        // do something
        // call service 5, service 6
        return null;
    }
}
```

Both public function **b** and **c** call to private function **d**. If I write test for function **b** and **c**, I will at least 2 case: "arg1 equal arg2" and "arg1 not equal arg2" for each function test. Which of the following solutions is correct? :

- Solution 1: function `testb` have 2 case, I have to create mock for service 5,6. Then function `testc` I have 2 case, create mock for service 5,6 too. I see it's quite duplicate workload, because I have to "go through" function **d** two times.
- Solution 2: I don't care value of `$arg1` and `$arg2`. I mock function **d**, expect it returns any value which I want. Then I finally I will write a function `testd`. But I have no technical for this solution.
- Solution 3: Seperate function **d** into a new class `serviceD` and public it. Then inject `serviceD` into class `a`. Now function `b` and `c` like:

```
$result = $this->serviceD->d($arg1, $arg2);
```

and I easily mock serviceD. But if I don't want to create new class? I still want to use solution 2.

Answer (score -1):

I would like to point out a thing. As you already seem to have SUT (System Under Test) code, you *know* how the code looks like, so you try to take a decision based on this.

That's technically wrong and a *no-no* from my standpoint. You should not write tests based on code "shape" and implementation. You should think about *what* a function (the public API for class clients) does in terms of input and output; the implementation is always a detail and you should not rely on it, because can change and if a test is written like that, things could quickly become cumbersome. Imagine when the *behaviour* of your code does not change, but the implementation does: you'll end up changing test code (nearly) every time SUT code *implementation* changes.

Having said that, the only "correct" answer is that we don't have all the details to provide a good answer. Maybe SUT class is doing "to much", violating the SRP, so the solution would be to split code. Maybe, if you think about the *behaviour* and not the implementation, the answer is already there. And so on.

But if you would like a personal opinion on solutions proposed, keeping in mind the high level of abstraction in this context, I would say:

Solution 1: if SUT has no reason to be splitted, you should don't care about `function d` in terms of its implementation, but in terms of what it does. After that, as you should "don't look" at the code, if `function b` and `function c` behaviour is the same (apart from `service3` and `service4`), you should "accept" a sort of duplication as a "setup" for the test to work.

Solution 2: I would go for this only if you're writing test for legacy code that has a lot of different execution paths inside `function d`, and you know you gonna refactor it. In this kind of scenario, you would like to reduce at a minimum level all the possible execution path, as what gives you value is `function b` and `function c` behaviour, and you know the class will be refactored.

Solution 3: It depends on the context, as said earlier.